# Binding a Function to "Search" button in Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an UITextField to search the word that typed there. I set the returnKeyType as UIReturnKeySearch. But I couldn't figure how to bind a function that I created, to the "Search" button at the keyboard.

```
self.searchWord.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeySearch;
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you need to implement the UITextfield delegate:

In your header file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

Then implement the delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextfield {        
    // Only do search when user hits return key on the search textfield.
    if ([aTextfield isEqual:self.searchTextField]) {
        // Method that does the search.
        [self doSearch];
    }

    return YES;
}
```